# bootstrap 5 - multiple modals

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Based on this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

button to invoke modal

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-sm" data-bs- 
 toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editpass" 
 data-bs-category="$row['category']" 
 data-bs-username="$row['username']" 
 data-bs-cid="$row['cid']"  
 data-bs-hostname="$row['hostname']" 
 data-bs-pw="generateStrongPassword('8', false, 'luds')" 
 data-bs-id="$row['id']"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-fw fa-lg 
 me-10px"></i></button>
```

I have a modal like so.

```
            <!-- modal for '.$row['element'].' editpass-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editpass">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Pass for </h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
              </div>
              
              <div class="modal-body">
              <form action="../includes/actions.php" method="POST">
              
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_password">                        
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username">
                <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid">
                <div class="form-group g-mb-20">
                  <label class="form-label" for="password">Password (Auto Generated)</label> 
                  <div class="input-group">   
                      <input id="password" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-braille"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <BR>
                  <!-- Toggles Radio -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-check form-switch">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="pass_options" type="radio" value="1" checked="">
                        <label class="form-label"><span>Apply to single record</span> </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Toggles Radio -->
                  
                  <!-- Toggles Radio -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-check form-switch">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="pass_options" type="radio" value="2">
                        <label class="form-label"><span class="modal-username">Apply to all with username</span></label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Toggles Radio -->
                  
                  <!-- Toggles Radio -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-check form-switch">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="pass_options" type="radio" value="3">
                        <label class="form-label"><span class="modal-category">Apply to all in category </span></label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Toggles Radio -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End '.$row['element'].' pass modal window -->
```

I then have corresponding javascript at the bottome like this

```
 var editpass = document.getElementById('editpass')
 editpass.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 // Button that triggered the modal
 var button = event.relatedTarget
 // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
 var hostname = button.getAttribute('data-bs-hostname')
 var id = button.getAttribute('data-bs-id')
 var cid = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cid')
 var category = button.getAttribute('data-bs-category')
 var username = button.getAttribute('data-bs-username')
 var pw = button.getAttribute('data-bs-pw')
 // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
 // and then do the updating in a callback.
 //
 // Update the modal's content.
 var modalTitle = editpass.querySelector('.modal-title')
 var modalUsername = editpass.querySelector('.modal-username')
 var modalCategory = editpass.querySelector('.modal-category')
 var modalCID = editpass.querySelector('.modal-cid')
 var modalID = editpass.querySelector('.modal-id')
 var modalPw = editpass.querySelector('.modal-body input')

 modalTitle.textContent = 'Editing passwords for ' + hostname
 modalUsername.textContent = 'Apply to all with username ' + username
 modalCategory.textContent = 'Apply to all in category ' + category
 modalPw.value = pw
 })
```

I can get username and category to display just fine, and I confirmed pw is being passed correctly, as I can change modalUsername.textContent = 'Apply to all with username ' + pw
for example and it shows the password. I am having a hell of a time figuring out why the input value won't get inputted. I have no errors in console and looking for a little guidance.

On this particular page, its a datatable with around 330 rows and each one can pop the modal with vars passed from the data-bs-attributes. As mentioned, username and category are fine, but cant get the password  to show anything. Once I figure this one out, I should be able to do the hidden inputs as well, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

var modalPw = editpass.querySelector('#password')

that seemed to do the trick for me, but I dont understand why.

Comment: Because using `editpass.querySelector('#password')` directly selects the element with ID of `password`. However, the one you were using before, `editpass.querySelector('.modal-body input')` selects an `input` tag within your `.modal-body` class. And if you look closely, there are multiple (4 to be specific). So it didn't know what to put in.